How to start a replication with psycopg3?
How can I start the replication with psycopg3? Or is this only supported by psycopg2 so far?
In psycopg2, one would create a connection with connection_factory = psycopg2.extras.LogicalReplicationConnection and then call start_replication on a cursor. Is there a similar connection factory available in psycopg3?

According to this GitHub issue, it hasn't been implemented yet. It looks as if the implementation attempt has stalled, as there are no recent updates.
